# Multisite WP - rewrite URL of post type results into a 404 in the rest of the pages

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, multisite

So I have a multisite Wordpress site that has a post type called Resources (can either be blogs or videos) and a taxonomy called Resources Types for blog or video. I want the taxonomy to go into the url as url.com/blog/post-name and not url.com/resource/blog/post-name.
Whenever I do my functions, all pages go 404. Removing the resource_tax function solves it all, so that's the conflictive part. Here's how I register the post type and add the taxonomy to the url:

```
add_action('init', 'test_resources_init');
function test_resources_init()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Resources', 'Test'),
        'singular_name' => __('Resource', 'Test'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'Test'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Resource', 'Test'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Resource', 'Test'),
        'new_item' => __('New Resource', 'Test'),
        'all_items' => __('All Resources', 'Test'),
        'view_item' => __('View Resource', 'Test'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Resources', 'Test'),
        'not_found' => __('No Resource found', 'Test'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Resources found in Trash', 'Test'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => __('Resources', 'Test')
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'with_front' => true ,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-playlist-video',
        'rewrite' => array ( 'slug' => __('%resource_type%'),'with_front' => true ), // change the name
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    );
    register_post_type('resource', $args);

}


function resource_tax( $post_link, $post ){
  if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'resource' ){
      $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'resource_type' );
      if( $terms ){
          return str_replace( '%resource_type%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
      }
  }
  return $post_link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'resource_tax', 1, 2 );
```

and how I'm registering the taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_resource_type_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );

function create_resource_type_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Resource Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Resource Types' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Resource Types' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Resource Types' ),
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'resource_type','with_front' => false ),
  );

  register_taxonomy('resource_type', array('resource'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'with_front' => false ,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => false,'with_front' => false ),
  ));
}
```

Is this failing because of the multisite? I'm pretty sure this works in other regular Wordpress sites. Thanks in advance.